# Duplicate messages created by FileBeat

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

I'm using FileBeat to load log messages into ElasticSearch through LogStash. The log files are located on Windows network share. The FileBeat runs on Linux machine, where Windows share is mapped via cifs. The problem is that some log file records are duplicated. What is interesting is the fact that duplicate records are created in moments separated in time by event some hours. In log files of FileBeat and LogStash I don't see anything critical. I know that it is not recommended to load logs with FileBeat from network share. It is said that there is a problem with inode values reuse. But I don't see records for one file with different inode values in FileBeat registry file. What could be the reason of duplicate messages created by FileBeat?

**Update**. There is my filebeat.yml:

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
    - \\<host_name>\<folder>\*.<service_name>.*.2019*.log
    - \\<host_name>\<folder>\*.<service_name>.*.2019*.log...
  encoding: Windows-1251
  multiline.pattern: '^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}'
  multiline.negate: true
  multiline.match: after  

filebeat.config.modules:
  path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml
  reload.enabled: false

setup.template.settings:
  index.number_of_shards: 3

output.logstash:
  hosts: ["<some_ip_address>:5044"]
  enabled: true

processors:
  - add_host_metadata: ~
  - add_cloud_metadata: ~
```

Comment: Just speculating here, but perhaps your log rotation is moving the current log to an archive log. (e.g my-log.log to my-log.log1) and this file is also being consumed by filebeat?

Comment: If this is the case then I think I would see it as different source in different log records, but it is not the case here.

Comment: Update your question with your filebeat and logstash configuration so people can try to help you.

Comment: They do not recommend reading log files from network volumes. Whenever possible, install Filebeat on the host machine and send the log files directly from there. Reading files from network volumes (especially on Windows) can have unexpected side effects. For example, changed file identifiers may result in Filebeat reading a log file from scratch again. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/faq.html#filebeat-network-volumes

Answer (score 0):

Remove the directory `/var/lib/filebeat/registry` and that should fix it, it did in my case.